# Copy properties from source to target class using beanutils.properties method

Tags: spring, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a source class Entity having some params and a target class Dto class.
Now, Entity class is having params of some other class but in dto class I'm using those params directly not using the other class reference in dto.

Problem is : while doing `BeanUtils.copyProperties(source,target)` those properties having reference to other class does not get copies to dto class.

Entity class:

```
Public class Entity{
   private A a;
   private String add;
}
Public class A{
  private String name;
}
Dto class :
public class Dto{
  private String add;
  private String name;     // here instead of class A i directly took the param of class A as per requirement.
}
```

How can I do `BeanUtils.copyProperties(Entity,Dto);` so that all properties get copied.

The entity class contains params from other entity class but dto does not contain the reference to other class instead directly having other class params.

Comment: Formatting/clarity

Answer (score 0):

Spring has the concept of Converters that are used automatically when it has to convert between classes. `BeanUtils.copyProperties` doesn't seem to use it, but it's should be difficult using `BeanWrapper` to write an alternative that loops over properties and attempts to use Converters (in this case a Converter from A to String) to copy the properties.

Alternatively there are other libraries that can do similar tasks: [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/), [ModelMapper](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper), [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) just to name a few without any preference.